# What is the point of implementing an interface in go?

Tags: go, oop, design-patterns

This code bellow gives `runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`, curious why enters the if clause and what is the point of implementing an interface in go if that if verifies for having the function without "implementing". The `Module` keyword within the `Media` creates the property `Module` within itself, that seems to act as a property of struct but also inherits its functions.

```
package main

type Module interface {
    Init()
}

type Media struct {
    Module // <- Why?
}

// func (m *Media) Init() {}

func main() {

    var v any = &Media{}

    if module, isModule := v.(Module); isModule {
        module.Init()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for a type T to implement an interface I, T must define all the methods of I. What you did is you embedded I into T, so effectively you defined a member variable of type `Module` in `Media`. Because of embedding, type `Module` implements `Media`, but the field `Media` is nil because it was never initialized.

The correct way to implement `Media` is:

```
type Media struct {
}

// This implements the Module.Init() method
func (m *Media) Init() {
}
```

After this, `*Media` implements `Module`.